# How can a paramagnetic element be a permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, elements

I'm just starting with magnetism and stuff and I was reading about different types of magnetism. Such as ferromagnetism, anti-ferromagnetism and paramagnetism. If I understand it correctly, examples of ferromagnetic elements are Iron, Cobalt and Nickel. They are permanent magnets (if the crystal structure is correct). But paramagnetic elements (and anti-ferromagnetic elements) will act like a magnet if there is an external magnetic field applied to it. But how can a Neodymium magnet, very well known permanent magnet, be one when its a paramagnetic element? ([Source properties Neodymium](http://periodictable.com/Elements/060/data.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Neodymium magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet) are not made of elemental Neodymium.

They are $Nd_2Fe_{14}B$